# How to customise drawer navigation with react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

[image: Drawer Requirement]

I want to create the customised drawer navigation for react native application as show in above image. I want suggestion if I could build this with any other libraries or how to customise this layout with react navigation.

I am well aware with the simple drawer navigation given by react-navigation, but I want to customise the open Stack screen as below when the drawer is open

I am using the latest version of react native and react-navigation.
currently i.e.

```
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.0.5",
```

Comment: There are a lot of info needed, such as which version of `react-navigation` you're using, share with us how you've configured your `react-navigation`

Comment: I am adding information above in question

Answer (score 0):

In react navigation v5 has option drawerType props you can play with that value

```
<Drawer.Navigator drawerType="" /> // look option in updated docs.
```

Comment: using drawerType='slide', it gives me the required behaviour, but still I want to minimize the view of the open screen and have no idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use drawerContent prop of Drawer.Navigator. Note: This support is in react navigation 5. Earlier version may or may not support.

```
function DrawerComponent(props) {
       return (
         // customized drawer here
       )
    }


    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerComponent {...props} />}
    >
    ...
    </Drawer.Navigator>
```